# Java call a method from object

Tags: java

So if i have a class which has an object from another class:

```
public class Test {

    private ObjectClass object;

    public Test (){
        object = new ObjectClass();
    }

    public void testMethod(){
        //does something
    }
}
```

ObjectClass:

```
public class ObjectClass {

    public void callMethod(){
        //call method from class Test
    }

}
```

How can the object call the method testMethod?

I know something similar could be achieved using a Runnable, but I also need some parameters so it isn't an option.

Comment: It's just `object.callMethod()`... Not quite sure why that would confuse you being that you are talking about how you have worked w/threads

Comment: If `ObjectClass` needs to call a method on `Test` then it needs a reference to an instance of `Test`.  Likely either passed to the `callMethod` method or to the `ObjectClass` constructor.

Comment: David has provided a way to do what you want. Now I suggest you ask yourself why you need to do this.

Comment: What about a Dependency Injection framework? You could inject an instant of Test into ObjectClass that way... although I admit it might be overkill :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the child object the parents own instance:

```
public class Test {
    private ObjectClass object;

    public Test (){
        object = new ObjectClass(this);
    }

    public void testMethod(){
        //does something
    }
}
```

ObjectClass:

```
public class ObjectClass {
    Test parentInstance;

    public ObjectClass(Test instance){
        parentInstance = instance;
    }

    public void callMethod(){
        parentInstance.testMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then `ObjectClass` needs a reference to an instance of `Test`.  Since `Test` isn't invoking `callMethod()` then I assume something else is?  Unless that something else can provide that instance to the method itself, `ObjectClass` will need to hold on to an instance.

One way to do this would be to pass an instance on the constructor.  For example:

```
public class ObjectClass {

    private final Test test;

    public ObjectClass(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void callMethod() {
        this.test.testMethod();
    }

}
```

In `Test` when creating your instance of `ObjectClass` you'd provide it with the reference it needs:

```
object = new ObjectClass(this);
```